# Parallel.ForEach behaving like a regular for each towards the end of the iteration

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am having this issue when I ran something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dataTable.AsEnumerable(), row =>
{
   //do processing
}
```

Assuming that there are 500+ records say 870. Once the Parallel.ForEach completes 850, it seems to be running sequentially i.e. only 1 operation at a time. It completed 850 operations very fast but when it comes close to the end of the iteration it becomes very slow and seems to be performing like a regular for each. I even tried for 2000 records.

Is something wrong in my code? Please give suggestions.

Below is the code I am using

Sorry I just posted the wrong example. This is the correct code:

```
Task newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(dtResult.AsEnumerable(), dr =>
    {
        string extractQuery = "";
        string downLoadFileFullName = "";
        lock (foreachObject)
        {

            string fileName = extractorConfig.EncodeFileName(dr);
            extractQuery = extractorConfig.GetExtractQuery(dr);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extractQuery)) throw new Exception("Extract Query not found. Please check the configuration");

            string newDownLoadPath = CommonUtil.GetFormalizedDataPath(sDownLoadPath, uKey.CobDate);
            //create folder if it doesn't exist
            if (!Directory.Exists(newDownLoadPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(newDownLoadPath);
            downLoadFileFullName = Path.Combine(newDownLoadPath, fileName);
        }
        Interlocked.Increment(ref index);

        ExtractorClass util = new ExtractorClass(SourceDbConnStr);
        util.LoadToFile(extractQuery, downLoadFileFullName);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref uiTimerIndex);
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide full code block

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a comment or an answer, but I feel it needs to be pointed out: `DataTable` is not a thread-safe type. So if your `//do processing` code involves any kind of modification at all (even to cells within individual rows), you're asking for a world of pain, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok for every row in the dataTable it will make a call to the database fetch the data and load it into a file. Its like an extraction process. Fetching data from database and extracting to a file.

Comment: @bunny When you say it appears to be running sequentially, what evidence do you have for this? Are you printing out thread ids for instance to get a rough feel for this?

Comment: In every iteration it creates and writes data to a file. I am checking the files and seems to be only 1 file is getting updated even though there are other iterations need to be completed.

Comment: @bunny **Tip** Include @usernames when replying to comments and that user will be notified. cheers, chiba.

Comment: @chibacity I don't about this. Will surely do from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess:

This looks to have a high degree of potential IO from:

- Database+Disk
- Network communication to DB and back
- Writing results to disk

Therefore a lot of time is going to be spent waiting for IO. My guess is that the waiting is only getting worse as more threads are being added to the mix and IO is being further stressed. For instance a disk only has one set of heads, so you cannot write to it concurrently. If you have a large number of threads trying to write concurrently, performance degrades.

Try limiting the maximum number of threads you are using:

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };

Parallel.ForEach(dtResult.AsEnumerable(), options, dr =>
{
    //Do stuff
});
```

**Update**

After your code edit, I would suggest the following which has a couple of changes:

- Reduce maximum number of threads - this can be experimented with.
- Only perform directory check and creation once.

Code:

```
private static bool isDirectoryCreated;

//...

var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };

Parallel.ForEach(dtResult.AsEnumerable(), options, dr =>
{
    string fileName, extractQuery, newDownLoadPath;

    lock (foreachObject)
    {
        fileName = extractorConfig.EncodeFileName(dr);

        extractQuery = extractorConfig.GetExtractQuery(dr);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extractQuery))
            throw new Exception("Extract Query not found. Please check the configuration");

        newDownLoadPath = CommonUtil.GetFormalizedDataPath(sDownLoadPath, uKey.CobDate);

        if (!isDirectoryCreated)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(newDownLoadPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newDownLoadPath);

            isDirectoryCreated = true;
        }
    }

    string downLoadFileFullName = Path.Combine(newDownLoadPath, fileName);

    Interlocked.Increment(ref index);

    ExtractorClass util = new ExtractorClass(SourceDbConnStr);
    util.LoadToFile(extractQuery, downLoadFileFullName);

    Interlocked.Increment(ref uiTimerIndex);
});
```

Comment: @chibacity I tried the suggestions. I guess its running the same, But thanks for pointing the correction in the code.

Comment: @bunny So limiting the number of threads made no improvement?

Comment: @chibacity It actually slowed down a little bit.

Comment: @chibacity no. I am trying actually the data is huge and it is taking lot of time loading some 7GB of data. I ll try to load small data and experiment with number of threads.

Comment: @bunny Agreed - If you have a very large dataset, it is often useful to try and get a smaller representative sample to experiment with. If you have massive amounts of IO though and little CPU, it's difficult to speed this up with threads.

Comment: @chibacity When I use ParallelOptions and set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount; It takes 5 minutes to load 650MB of data. But when I don't use the ParallelOptions it loads 1GB of data in 4 minutes. And also when the number of records in the data table are few say 7 and total size of all records are 8.7 MB it takes 6 minutes to load. I mean when few records are there it takes longer and when more records are available it is faster.

Comment: 4. When I tried with processor count = 2, It took 5 minutes to load 350 MB of data.

Answer (score 2):

It’s hard to give details without the relevant code but in general this is the expected behaviour. .NET tries to schedule the tasks such that every processor is evenly busy.

But this can only ever be approximated sind not all of the tasks take the same amount of time. At the end some processors will be done working and some won’t, and re-distributing the work is costly and not always beneficial.

I don’t know details about the load balancing used by PLinq but the bottom line is that this behaviour can never be fully prevented.